# How can I get stereo input to my video camera from mono source?

Tags: audio-recording

Currently running 1/4 from soundboard aux out to 1/8 into mic jack on video camera. Can I use a second aux out with a dual 1/4 mono to stereo mini to accomplish this? 
Would this also work in sending "stereo" output to my iPad Air into a recording app? 
We are recording sermons to put online and want to streamline the process as much as possible.
Thanks
Tod DeLisle

Answer (score 1):

You can bridge one mono output with two input channels, since input impedance is much higher than output impedance. You could easily wire your own cable or adapter -- connect ground to ground, and both 'hot' input wires to the one output wire.

Or you could buy a couple of 'Y' adapters. One would split the mono into two connectors, the other would combine those into the single input plug. Any 'Radio Shack' or similar store would have what you need. If you have two aux outputs you could skip the first Y splitter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the normal way to handle stereo output in the professional sound world.  Some boards do provide "stereo" out, but that is really just two main channel outputs that go out to individual mono outputs and are stereo linked.

Nicer boards will actually allow stereo linking of aux channels as well, but even if it isn't supported by the board directly, you can still fake it on your own.

You may also benefit by adding a pad to each of the lines.  Typically, the signal level out of a professional sound board is a bit higher than that expected by a consumer video camera and the signal quality will benefit from putting pads in line between the board and the recorder (either the camera or the iPad jack).